# How to solve empty array with $unwind?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a table and save like following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bd"), "count" : 1, "author" : "Tony", "music" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("571661cd4af77ca97a9614c1"), "count" : 2, "author" : "Tony" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614be"), "count" : 2, "author" : "Joe", "music" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("571661cd4af77ca97a9614c0"), "count" : 1, "author" : "Joe" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bf"), "count" : 3, "author" : "Mary", "music" : [ ] }
```

I hope to find the number of record that "$count" > "$music.count". But when I do {$unwind:"$music"}, I get following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bd"), "count" : 1, "author" : "Tony", "music" : { "_id" : ObjectId("571661cd4af77ca97a9614c1"), "count" : 2, "author" : "Tony" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614be"), "count" : 2, "author" : "Joe", "music" : { "_id" : ObjectId("571661cd4af77ca97a9614c0"), "count" : 1, "author" : "Joe" } }
```

The third record disappear. How can I get the result like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bd"), "count" : 1, "author" : "Tony", "music" : { "_id" : ObjectId("571661cd4af77ca97a9614c1"), "count" : 2, "author" : "Tony" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614be"), "count" : 2, "author" : "Joe", "music" : { "_id" : ObjectId("571661cd4af77ca97a9614c0"), "count" : 1, "author" : "Joe" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bf"), "count" : 3, "author" : "Mary", "music" : {"count": 0} }
```

The initial records are got by $loopup, The total code is like following:

```
db.bookAuthors.aggregate([{
$lookup:{from:"musicAuthors", localField:"author", foreignField:"author",as:"music"}},
{$unwind:"$music"},
{$project:{_id:"$author",count:1,music:1}},
{$match:{$gt:["$count","$music.count"]}},
{$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

How can I do to find the number of record that "$count" > "$music.count"? In this example, the result should be 2. But now due to the unwind problem, I get 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In MongoDB 3.2 ( which you are using if you have `$lookup` ) the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator has the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option. This changes the behaviour to "not" remove the document from results where the array is in fact "empty":

```js
db.bookAuthors.aggregate([
  { "$lookup":{
    "from": "musicAuthors", 
    "localField": "author", 
    "foreignField": "author",
    "as": "music"
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$music", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true },
  { "$project": {
      "count": 1,
      "author": 1,
      "music": {
        "$ifNull": [ "$music", { "$literal": { "count": 0 } }] },
      }
  }}
])
```

And the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) replaces the missing value in this case.

But actually since your association here is `1:1` then you could just forego the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) altogether, and simply replace the empty array:

```js
db.bookAuthors.aggregate([
  { "$lookup":{
    "from": "musicAuthors", 
    "localField": "author", 
    "foreignField": "author",
    "as": "music"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "count": 1,
    "author": 1,
    "music": {
      "$ifNull": [
        { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$music", 0 ] },
        { "$literal": { "count": 0 } }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

And there if [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) found nothing at the `0` index ( therefore "empty" ) then the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) would return the alternate value just as before. Of course where it did find something, then that value is returned instead.

But again, your specific problem still has a better solution, which again does not need [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). Since you can just calculate the "count" condition "in-line" with the array:

```js
db.bookAuthors.aggregate([
  { "$lookup":{
    "from": "musicAuthors", 
    "localField": "author", 
    "foreignField": "author",
    "as": "music"
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "count": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gt": [
              "$count",
              { "$sum": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$music",
                  "as": "el",
                  "in": "$$el.count"
                }
              }}
            ]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Here the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator is used in both of it's use cases, as it's traditional "accumulator" and new role in "summing" values in an array. The [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator looks at each array element and returns the value to `$sum` to produce a total. An "empty" array would return as `0`.

Then there is the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) comparison to determine if the returned total from the array was less than the `"count"` property on the document. Where `true` a `1` is returned for the accumulator, and where `false` it gets `0`.

The end result is of course `2`, since both the "first" and "third" documents actually match the condition inside the accumulator. So that really is the most efficient way to do this, even if it looks a bit "long winded" in the process.